# How do I move forward to find a better model fit, help interpreting DHARMa residuals

Tags: r, mixed-model, zero-inflation, glmmtmb

I am trying to test if there is an effect on number of individuals depending on the proportion of a certain land use type and its management. But I don't find a model with a good fit. There seems to be zero-inflation and I have tried to fit a zero-inflated model, but any way I try, the zero inflation test still tells me I have zero-inflation, and the residual patterns look bad. Maybe I am just overfitting, I don't have many observations (234) but pretty many variables in my model. Including the variables I am including makes ecological sense to me, and the ones I would want to exclude (as they are not the main interest) are significant. In the residual versus predicted plot created with `DHARMa` I see a hump shaped pattern (?). I have read that I should then try to add a quadratic term. But I don't understand on which variable and don't have experience using `poly()` or `I(^2)` and don't know how I should do that. Any help on how I can move forward to find a model that meets the model assumptions would be much appreciated!

This is my model without specified zero inflation:

```r
mod <-glmmTMB(Number.of.individuals~Landuse.s*Management+
    Year+Year:Management+
    Env1.s+Env2.s+Env3.s+Env4 +Env5 +Occasion+
    (1|Farm/Site/Occasion),family="nbinom2", 
    data=data)
```

and the one with (I have tried many versions of specifying the zero-inflation formula):

```r
zinbmod<-glmmTMB(Number.of.individuals~Landuse.s*Management+
    Year+Year:Management+
    Env1.s+Env2.s+Env3.s+Env4 +Env5 +Occasion+
   (1|Farm/Site/Occasion),family="nbinom2",
    ziformula = ~ 1, data=data)
```

".s" stands for standardized (standardized to zero mean and unit variance). Including `Env1.s` in `zinbmod` with this `ziformula`, makes the model fail. To include it I need to specify the `ziformula` as:

```r
ziformula = ~Env4
ziformula = ~Env3.s 
ziformula = ~Env3.s+Env4
ziformula = ~Env1.s 
ziformula = ~Management
```

Other combos I have tried make the model fail. All these produces a model with similar AIC to the above zinbmodel, but with worse BIC. All have bad residual patterns.
Removing `Farm` from the random structure does not improve things.
I have forgotten a lot of my statistical knowledge, and mathematics too, so trying to read up on this has not made me wiser.

I tried to add my data here, but the question become too long then...

When checking model assumptions with the help of `DHARMa`, this is what I see (for mod):

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

There is no spatial or temporal autocorrelation (not shown here but I have tested)
That y is red in the plot for Env4 is new since I changed the level names of other things into dummy names in order to make this post (and to post the data here)...
Can any one help me interpret these residual patterns, in order to move forward? What is the major problem with the models?